# How to precisely compute pitch, roll and yaw out of the 68 landmarks returned by face-api.js?

Tags: javascript, computer-vision, face-api

I am using face-api.js to extract facial landmarks from a video stream. 
Now I am trying to compute the head rotation based on these landmarks. 
I have been already able to estimate the roll and yaw.

I have also tried the opencv.js solvePnP way, but could not get precise enough results.

Any idea how the pitch could be computed/estimated ?

[image]